# When push forward a numerically trivial is numerically trivial?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

$X, Y$ are  algebraic varieties over field $k$. Two invertible sheaves $L, L^{\prime}$ on $X$ are called  numerically equivalent, denoted by $L \equiv L^{\prime}$, if $(L \cdot C)=\left(L^{\prime} \cdot C\right)$ for any  curve $C$.

Now let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be proper morphism. If $Q$ invertible sheaf on $Y$, by projection formula, one easily contains if $Q\equiv 0$, then $f^* Q\equiv 0$. Hence, we can talk about the natural linear map induced by $f$, that is, $f^*: N^1(Y)\rightarrow N^1(X)$. Here $N^1(Y)=NS(Y)\otimes\mathbb R$, which is a $\rho(Y)$- dimensional real vector space.

Naturally, we can consider when we can define $f_*: N^1(X)\rightarrow N^1(Y)$, if it can be defined, it is necessary that for a  numerically trivial, the push forward is still numerically trivial.

**So my question is** under what **(weakest!)** settings (about the varieties $X, Y$ and the morphism $f$), push forward a numerically trivial is numerically trivial?$\color{blue}{\textrm{(*)}}$

> Notice that if the above claim is right, some conditions should be satisfied:
> (1) push forward a line bundle is line bundle.
> (2) Although numerically equivalent cannot imply linearly equivalent sometimes. But if the above claim is right, $f_*\mathcal O_X=\mathcal O_Y$ is necessary.

So, I guess if $f$ finite surjective morphism of degree one, $X, Y$ regular (then $f$ automatically flat), can we get our claim? How?

**Some thought...**

If $C$ any curve on $X$, with $\left(L \cdot C\right)=0$. For any curve $C^\prime$ on $Y$, thanks to the surjective, one can  find curve $C$ on $X$, such that $C^\prime=f(C)$, then when can we have $\left(f_*L \cdot f(C)\right)=0$?

Any references and suggestion would be appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: If $X,Y$ are regular, then a finite map of degree one is an isomorphism.